# Prove $\frac{n^3 + 5n} 6 = v , v \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, induction, proof-explanation

Prove $\frac{n^3 + 5n} 6 = s , s \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

basic step: $\frac{1^3 + 5 ( 1) } 6 = 1$

assumption: $\frac{k^3 + 5k} 6 = s \in \mathbb{Z}$

proof: $\frac{(k + 1)^3 + 5(k + 1)}{6} = s \in \mathbb{Z}$

$$(k + 1)^3 + 5(k +1) = 6s$$

$$k^3 + 5k +3k^2 + 3k + 6 = 6s + 3k^2 + 3k + 6 = 6s + 3(k^2 + k) + 6$$

Could someone help me finish with this?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 mathjax reference

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889232/introductory-induction-proof-that-nn2-5-is-divisible-by-6?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{(k+1)^3+5(k+1)}{6} &=\frac{k^3+3k^2+3k+1+5k+5}{6}\\
&=\frac{(k^3+5k)}{6}+\frac66+\frac{3k(k+1)}{6}
\end{align}

Prove that $k(k+1)$ is even and you can complete the proof for positive integers.

You still have to argue for zero and negative number though it is easy.

Remark about your previous working:

You are suppose to prove $\exists s_2$ such that $\frac{(k+1)^3+5(k+1)}{6}=s_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ but it seems like you are starting from there.

Answer (score 0):

First note that using the same symbol $s $ for each step is confusing. You're making it seem as though the sequence is constant, but it isn't. What you're trying to prove (I'm guessing) is that $n^3 + 5n $ is always divisible by $6$

Assuming your inductive step for $n = k $, the case for $n =k+1$ becomes, as you put,

$$ 6s + 3k(k+ 1) + 6$$

One of $k $ and $k+1$ must be even, so $k (k+1) $ is also even. Thus we can write $k (k+1)  = 2p $ for some integer $p $.

Plugging this back in above, $$6s + 3 (k^2+k) +6 = 6s + 6p + 6 = 6 (s + p +1) $$

And so is divisible by $6$, so that
$$\frac{(k+1)^3 + 5 (k+1)}{6} = s'$$
For some integer $s'$

Answer (score 0):

For $(n^3 + 5n)$

$n=6k$,  the factorization is $6k(36k^2 + 5)$

$n=6k+1$,  the factorization is $6(1 + 6 k) (1 + 2 k + 6 k^2)$

$n=6k+2$,  the factorization is $6 (1 + 3 k) (3 + 8 k + 12 k^2)$

$n=6k+3$,  the factorization is $6 (1 + 2 k) (7 + 18 k + 18 k^2)$

$n=6k+4$,  the factorization is $6 (2 + 3 k) (7 + 16 k + 12 k^2)$

$n=6k+5$,  the factorization is $6 (5 + 6 k) (5 + 10 k + 6 k^2)$

So the rest is obvious.